# Why is the program not going trough my @override class

Tags: java, json, android-studio

I want to create multiple markers with longitude and latitude, so I wrote this pice of code somehow in my google maps activity the code is not running trough, because I get the first logcat output "jsonParse: is now in json Parse". Why is it stopping at my @override Method.

So I wrote a test project where I just print everything to a TextView and the code runs through. I don't understand why it does not work with my GoogleMaps andaroid project? The test project is working fine

Here is the Main Activity of the Maps Class:
The test version is the same code, but not run in an android studio GoogleMap project. The only difference is that in the test Project I call it in the on create.

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

private GoogleMap mMap;
private RequestQueue mQueue;
private static final String TAG = "xd";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

}


@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    jsonParse();
    mMap = googleMap;


   /* // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
    LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));*/
}

private void jsonParse() {

    String url = "https://api.myjson.com/bins/kp9wz";
    Log.d(TAG, "jsonParse: is now in jsonParse ");

    JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: is before try");
                    try {
                        JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("addresses");

                        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject address = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                            String firstName = address.getString("name");
                            Double latitude = Double.parseDouble(address.getString("latitude"));
                            Double longitude = Double.parseDouble(address.getString("longitude"));

                            LatLng sydney = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
                            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
                        }
                        Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: is after for loop");
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            error.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have created a request, but you haven't added your request to a request queue.

Comment: I had edited it, but with the request queue my app always stopped

Comment: I see that you've have elsewhere asked a new question, in which you actually send the request somewhere.  Is it your intention to just ignore this question now?